# Issue for scraping website data for every webpage automatically and save it in csv by using beautiful Soup, pandas and request

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The code can't scrape web data page by page successfully and the csv format doesn't match the web data record. I want to the code enable run all web pages automatically. Right now, it only can run first page data. How it can run second, third page by itself? Secondly, in csv format, 'hospital_name','name','license_type' columns are all empty in csv format. They all show up at the end of csv format

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

 url = "https://www.abvma.ca/client/roster/clientRosterView.html? 
 clientRosterId=168"
 url_page_2 = url + '&page=' + str(2)
 def get_data_from_url(url):

 #output the data       
 data = requests.get(url)
 page_data = soup(data.text,'html.parser')
 AB_data = page_data.find_all('div',{"class":"col-md-4 roster_tbl"})
 
 #create a table 
 #for each in AB_data:
 #print (each.text)

df=pd.DataFrame(AB_data)
df.head()   
df.drop([0,1,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12],axis=1, inplace=True)
for each in AB_data:
    hospital = each.find('a').text
    name = each.find('strong').text
    license_type=each.find('font').text
    #print(hospital)
    #df['hospital_name']= hospital
    df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'hospital_name':hospital,
    'name':name,'license_type':license_type},index=[0]), sort=False)
   pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
   print (df)
   df.to_csv('AB_Vets_2018.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: I'd recommend [Scrappy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) it has pagination feature.

Comment: You can always use a for loop to iterate through the pages

Answer (score 0):

#### * Python 3 *

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FIELDNAMES = (
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'license_type',
    'location',
    'reg_num'
)


def get_page(page_num):
    base_url = "https://www.abvma.ca/client/roster/clientRosterView.html"
    params = {
        'clientRosterId': 168,
        'page': page_num
    }
    r = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text


def parse_page(page_html):
    result = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
    for vet in soup.find_all('div', class_='col-md-4 roster_tbl'):
        name, *location, title, licence_type, reg_num = vet.stripped_strings
        last_name, first_name = name.split(', ', maxsplit=1)

        result.append({
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'license_type': licence_type,
            'location': '' if not location else location[0],
            'reg_num': int(reg_num.split()[-1])
        })
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    for page_num in range(1, 35):
        page_html = get_page(page_num)
        parsed_page = parse_page(page_html)
        result.extend(parsed_page)

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(result)
```

[Output CSV](https://bpaste.net/show/54c9b59721f3)

Comment: Thanks and It's really helpful!

Comment: @dinfan You could accept this answer if it helped solve your question.